# iText - Inconsistent HTML converting results

Tags: c#, docker, itext7

I'm running the same code while debugging on Mac and in Docker.

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
using (var pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(ms)))
{
    var fs = new FontSet();

    fs.AddDirectory("assets/fonts");

    Console.WriteLine("fontSet: " + string.Join(';', fs.GetFonts().Select(x => x.GetFontName())));

    try
    {
        HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(new MemoryStream(html.Content), pdf, new ConverterProperties().SetFontProvider(new FontProvider(fs)));
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { throw new AppError(ex, AppError.AppErrorCode.ITextHtmlConversionError); }

    ...
}
```

`assets/fonts` contains all the fonts necessary to render all of my template HTMLs. In Docker, I run Ubuntu and pre-register all the fonts using `fc-cache`.

Mac result is ok: cyrillic characters are all present; correctly enlarges `h1` tag; embeds two subset fonts (other than a full Helvetica): `Arial-BoldMT` and `ArialNarrow`.

Docker result is almost none: cyrillic is not converted; necessary fonts are not embedded automatically; h1 is not enlarged and the whole document becomes essentially plain-text.

I confirmed that installed fonts on both OSes are the same set.

What needs to be done in Docker Ubuntu image to work as expected?